# What is the meaning of "Register.Rd"?

Tags: microprocessor, computers, cpu, computer-architecture, register

Reading Hennessy's book "Computer Organization and Design" it is mentioned "Register.Rd" and "Register.Rs" but what does it mean? The .Rd, .Rt and .Rs parts I can't understand, on page 365:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are just generic ways of referring to cpu registers:

- Rd is usually denotes a destination register.
- Rs, Rt usually denote source registers.

For example, a cpu instruction could be:

`add Rs,Rt,Rd`

Which would mean: `Rd = Rs+Rt`

The Rd,Rs,Rt are placeholders for the actual registers used in this instruction.  A specific example for this instruction could be:

`add $1,$2,$3`

Which would mean "write the sum of specific cpu registers `$1` and `$2` into `$3`".

Answer (score 5):

I'm not very familiar with this exact subject, but within instruction sets tables for microcontrollers these conventions are often used:

- rd : destination register
- rs : first source register
- rt : second source register

This looks quite similar with your quote.